# Реализация функции __sync_val_compare_and_swap для Sparc V8

Tags: c, ассемблер

Имеется кросс компилятор под архитектуру Sparc. Но он не поддерживает Built-in functions for atomic memory access. Меня интересует функция `__sync_val_compare_and_swap (long *ptr, long oldval long newval)`

она выполняет атомарную операцию сравнения и обмена: That is, if the current value of *ptr is oldval, then write newval into *ptr.

Вот есть реализация для i386:
Код:

```
struct __xchg_dummy { unsigned long a[100]; };
#define __xg(x) ((struct __xchg_dummy *)(x))

static inline unsigned long __cmpxchg(volatile void *ptr, unsigned long old,
                  unsigned long new, int size)
{
   unsigned long prev;
   switch (size) {
   case 1:
      __asm__ __volatile__(LOCK_PREFIX "cmpxchgb %b1,%2"
                 : "=a"(prev)
                 : "q"(new), "m"(*__xg(ptr)), "0"(old)
                 : "memory");
      return prev;
   case 2:
      __asm__ __volatile__(LOCK_PREFIX "cmpxchgw %w1,%2"
                 : "=a"(prev)
                 : "q"(new), "m"(*__xg(ptr)), "0"(old)
                 : "memory");
      return prev;
   case 4:
      __asm__ __volatile__(LOCK_PREFIX "cmpxchgl %1,%2"
                 : "=a"(prev)
                 : "q"(new), "m"(*__xg(ptr)), "0"(old)
                 : "memory");
      return prev;
   }
   return old;
}

#define cmpxchg(ptr,o,n)\
   ((__typeof__(*(ptr)))__cmpxchg((ptr),(unsigned long)(o),\
               (unsigned long)(n),sizeof(*(ptr))))
```

Кто-нибудь знаком с написанием ассемблерных вставок (для кода на языке C) под архитектуру Sparc V8? Буду очень благодарен помощи

Comment: Врят ли `Sparc` умеет это делать. Судя по [документации](http://www.gaisler.com/doc/sparcv8.pdf), тут есть только атомарный `swap` и есть барьер записи - `stbar`. Можно попробовать заменить `cmpxchg` на цепочку `stbar -> cmp -> swap`.

Comment: Посмотрите исходники ядра [Linux](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/sparc/lib/atomic32.c#L82)

Answer (score 2):

Для Sparc то же самое делается инструкциями под названиями CASA и CASXA. Можете посмотреть, например, во FreeBSD: [функции](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/sys/sparc64/include/cpufunc.h?revision=326262&view=markup): см. `casa`, `casxa`, и их [использование](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/sys/sparc64/include/atomic.h?revision=327053&view=markup) `atomic_cas_32`, `atomic_cas_64`.